# Visual Studio Community Issue (Setup detected an issue during the operation...)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I try to install **Visual Studio 2015 (Community**) there is an error message.

```
Setup detected an issue during the operation. Please click below to check for a solution and help us improve the setup experience.
```

I read the possible procedures but I cannot resolve it.

I launched the setup, I got the error, I launched `Collect.exe` to get the logs file (*vslogs.cab*) and this is the [Link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5B43403A5158C419!1409&authkey=!AI1yr8haqKVaowU&ithint=file%2Ccab)

P.S. I have Windows 10 Home

Comment: what are your language/time settings? Setup fails b ecause it thins the time is wrong: **ERROR: FileTime Win32 non valido.** change the time settings in Windows to EN-US and try again.

Comment: Hi Andre, Thank you for the reply! However i have Italian setted, i try en/us but not work :( the same error!

Comment: I resolve the problem restoring system fonts. Thank You!

Comment: ok, post this as answer (with ore details what you did) and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

1) Make a backup of fonts of your system
2) Try Deleting Them ( skip fonts that can't be deleted )
That's it,  after installation restore them from backup.